# How can I derive a key pair from mnemonic phrase successfully in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, sha, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to create a simple cryptocurrency for which I made a wallet in Node.JS using the bip39 and crypto module. The plan is to be able to create a wallet so that the script generates a random mnemonic phrase and from that a private and public key. The same mnemonic should result in the same key pair, while different mnemonics should result in different pairs.

For some reason, if after generation I try to generate the same private/public key from the same mnemonic as before, a different key pair is returned. I'm just learning cryptography, I might be doing something very wrong. Anyway, thanks in advance for your help, here is my code:

```
function generateRandomMnemonic() {
  // Generate a random 256-bit (32-byte) entropy
  const entropy = crypto.randomBytes(32);

  // Convert the entropy to a mnemonic phrase
  const mnemonic = bip39.entropyToMnemonic(entropy);

  return mnemonic;
}

function generateKeyPairFromMnemonic(mnemonic) {
  // Derive a seed from the mnemonic phrase
  const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);

  // Generate key pair from the seed
  const keyPair = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'spki',
      format: 'pem',
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'pkcs8',
      format: 'pem',
    },
    seed,
  });

  return keyPair;
}

function getAddress(publicKey) {
    const addressHash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(publicKey).digest('hex').slice(-30);
    return `csc.${addressHash}`
}

function signTransaction(transaction, privateKey) {
    const dataToSign = JSON.stringify(transaction);

    // Sign the data correctly
    const sign = crypto.createSign('sha256');
    sign.update(JSON.stringify(transaction));
    const signature = sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64');

    return signature;
}
```

The code where the wallet is generated:

```
app.get('/signup', async (req, res) => {
    const mnemonic = generateRandomMnemonic();
    const keypair = generateKeyPairFromMnemonic(mnemonic);
    const address = getAddress(keypair.publicKey);

    console.log("Generated address: ", address);

    req.session.mnemonic = mnemonic;
    req.session.address = address;

    res.render(DIRECTORY + "/register.html", {mnemonic:mnemonic});
});
app.get('/signin', async (req, res) => {
    res.render(DIRECTORY + "/login.html");
});
app.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
    let mnemonic = req.body.mnemonic;

    const keypair = generateKeyPairFromMnemonic(mnemonic);
    const address = getAddress(keypair.publicKey);

    req.session.mnemonic = mnemonic;
    req.session.address = address;
    res.redirect('/success');
});
```

Should I use elliptic curve instead?

Comment: Where is the `const keyPair = generateKeyPairFromMnemonic(generateRandomMnemonic())` call?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It is called perfectly, but I'm afraid that something is wrong with the hashing functions itself, not the call. I'll include the calling as well in the question if it helps though

Comment: AFAIK, [`generateKeyPairSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptogeneratekeypairsynctype-options) can not process a seed (presumably the seed is just ignored). Have a look at the documentation. Furthermore, cryptocurrencies use [ECC](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/asymmetric-key-ciphers/elliptic-curve-cryptography-ecc) and not RSA, s. also ECDSA, [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) (among others, handles the creation of a master key from a seed, possibly that's what you're looking for), BIP39, BIP44... Your question is currently much too broad for SO.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it! I've tried it with using hdkey and secp256k1 instead and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const bip39 = require('bip39');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const elliptic = require('elliptic');

function generateKeyPairFromMnemonic(mnemonic) {
  // Derive a seed from the mnemonic phrase
  const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);

  // Create an elliptic curve key pair
  const ec = new elliptic.ec('secp256k1');
  const keyPair = ec.genKeyPair({
    entropy: seed.slice(0, 32), // Take the first 32 bytes of the seed for entropy
  });

  return {
    privateKey: keyPair.getPrivate('hex'),
    publicKey: keyPair.getPublic('hex'),
  };
}

// Example usage
const mnemonic = 'your twelve word mnemonic phrase';
const keyPair = generateKeyPairFromMnemonic(mnemonic);
console.log('Private Key:', keyPair.privateKey);
console.log('Public Key:', keyPair.publicKey);
```